# How to link to external libraries using python sphinx?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, python-moderngl

I have a python module documented on RTD: http://modernglexttextools.readthedocs.io

This is an extension of [another module](https://moderngl.readthedocs.io) and I want to link between the two. I want the parameters and the return types to work as a link. Here is an [example](https://moderngl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/Context.html#ModernGL.Context.texture).

My **conf.py**

```
extensions = [
    'sphinx.ext.autodoc',
    'sphinx.ext.githubpages',
    'sphinx.ext.intersphinx',    # added this but does not help
    'sphinxcontrib.napoleon'
]
```

Here is an example for a method with an external class linked. The external class is `ModernGL.Context`. I am not sure if I have to configure where this class is documented. But it should point to [this link](https://moderngl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/Context.html).

```
def load(filename, convert=None, ctx=None) -> ModernGL.Texture:
    '''
        Load a texture. If ctx is ``None`` the default_context is used.

        Args:
            filename (str): The name of the file to load.

        Keyword Args:
            convert (str): Convert the texture before loading. Possible values are: ('L', 'RGB', 'RGBA')
            ctx (:py:class:`ModernGL.Context`): The Context to use for loading the texture.

        Returns:
            :py:class:`ModernGL.Texture`: The texture.

        Examples:

            .. code-block:: python

                import ModernGL
                from ModernGL.ext import textools

                ctx = ModernGL.create_standalone_context()
                # ctx = ModernGL.create_context()

                texture = textools.load('brick.jpg', ctx=ctx)
                texture.use()
    '''
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If I understand your question, it sounds like you want to only add a link from your docs to theirs, and not include their docs in yours.

Adding the Sphinx extension to `extensions` in your `conf.py` is only one piece of its usage.  You also need to define an `intersphinx_mapping` which is a dict that tells the extension where to look for external documentation. For example:

```
# Looks for objects in external projects
intersphinx_mapping = {
    'moderngl': ('https://moderngl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/', None),
}
```

Finally to create the specific link, use this syntax:

```
:py:class:`ModernGL.Context`
```

Additionally, linking to arbitrary [targets](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/markup/inline.html#role-ref) can be done with the following syntax, assuming the targets exist:

```
:ref:`My Label <moderngl:MyArbitraryTarget>`
```

Comment: The ``:ref:`My Label <moderngl:Context>` `` link does not work ("WARNING: undefined label: moderngl:context"). In order to link to the Context class, ``:py:class:`ModernGL.Context` `` works fine.

Comment: Please edit the answer according to @mzjn 's comment and I will accept it.